# How to detect whether the Property value(ReferenceType property) is changed in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reference-type

I have a `Customer` class, I would like to get notified when the user has changed the value of the `Customer.CityInfo` property.

```
public class City
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
}

public class Customer
{

    private City cityInfo;
    private string name;

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCityModified { get; set;}
    public bool IsCustomerNameModified { get; set; }

    public string Name 
    { 
        get{ return name;} 
        set
        {
           if(name!=value)
           {
              IsCustomerNameModified=true; }name=value;
           } 
        }
     }


    public City CityInfo 
    {
    get
        {
           if(cityInfo==null)
           {
              cityInfo=new City();
           }
           return cityInfo;
         }

      set{
          if(this.cityInfo!=value)
          {
             IsCityModified =true;
          }
          this.cityInfo=value;
       }   
  }
}

public ActionResult Save()
{
    Customer customer=this.currentCustomerSession;
    if(TryUpdateModel<Customer>(customer)){
       UpdateModel<Customer>(customer)
    }
    if(customer.IsCustomerNameModified ){
        //I am able to detect whether the customerName value has been changed in the frontend.
    }
    if(customer.IsCityModified){
        //I am not able to detect whether the city value has been changed in the frontend.
    }
}
```

I could set the flag(IsCustomerNameModified) to true if the Customer Name changed since its a value type. But Not able to detect the changes done in Reference Types.

Could anyone help?

Comment: How does the user communicate with the app? through a win form?

Comment: A string is not a value type, it's an (immutable) reference type.

Comment: May I ask why you want to know if it changed or not? In some cases validating if all the field have changed to do a smaller update just takes more time than updating everything. But maybe you have another reason that I don't know :)

Comment: @Fjodr I am using MVC forms to update.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of issue is usually handled via a change notification system. See this article: [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Snippet:

```
  public string PersonName
  {
      get { return name; }
      set
      {
          name = value;
          // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
          OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
      }
  }

  // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

Using this pattern will help you avoid the need to set flags or other such machinations.

Comment: I implemented your solution as below 

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

but each time the PropertyChanged is being null. I am afraid.



, But OnPropertyChanged() fires

Comment: @Sravan: Read that linked article closely. You actually need to add an event handler so it will fire. It will not fire if no one is listening (it's null.) Also please do not paste code into comments. It's VERY hard to read. If you change code please add it to your original question

Answer (score 0):

Now that I correctly understood the problem, I would suggest to do the following:

Add a `public bool Changed { get; private set; }` property in your `City` object.

Then in each property of your object, check if the value has changed, and if it has, then put the `Changed` flag to true:

```
public int Id
{
   { get { return this.id } }
   {
      set
      {
         if (this.id != value) Changed = true;
         this.id = value;
      }
   }
}
```

it is similar to implementing the `IPropertyChanged` interface, but this way you are sure you only get to check if the object was modified once.

It seems that the reference of your object doesn't change, so you only have to check it's `Changed` property (if the object's reference really changed, my precedent answer would have worked)

Comment: I have tried the above but the this.cityInfo value has got changed when accessing this.cityInfo.Id itself. So (this.cityInfo.Id != value.Id) always false. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: replaced my answer since my last one was irrelevant after the precision you made in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Paul is correct you need to implement INotifyProperty change. Here is a quick example. It's very simple.

```
  public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private int _number;

        public BaseViewModel()
        {
            PropertyChanged += (o, p) =>
                                   {
                                       //this is the place you would do what you wanted to do
                                       //when the property has changed.
                                   };
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public int Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
            set
            {
                _number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But doing this the PropertyChanged event is catched every time you manipulate with instance of model e.g select it

Comment: Just check to see if it is actually different in the setter if(_number != value) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paul's answer but you may even need to override the Equals() and GetHashCode() functions in the City class. The overridden function can check to see if the Code and ID have changed.

```
public override bool Equals( object obj )
{
    City other = obj as City;

    if ( ( other != null ) && ( other.Id == this.Id ) && ( other.Code == this.Code ) )
    {
        return ( true );
    }

    return ( false );
}

public override int GetHashCode( )
{
    return ( this.Id ^ this.Code.GetHashCode() ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use INotifyPropertyChanged , but I guess you are not binding the object to some UI element.
In that case if it is required only to know if the CityInfo property is changed, the simplest
solution is to raise a custom event.

```
public class Customer
{

    private City cityInfo;
    private string name;

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCityModified { get; set;}
    public event Action<City> OnCityInfoChanged;
    public bool IsCustomerNameModified { get; set; }

    public string Name 
    { 
        get{ return name;} 
        set
        {
           if(name!=value)
           {
              IsCustomerNameModified=true; }name=value;
           } 
        }
     }


    public City CityInfo 
    {
    get
        {
           if(cityInfo==null)
           {
              cityInfo=new City();
           }
           return cityInfo;
         }

      set{
          if(this.cityInfo ==value)
                  return;
             IsCityModified =true;
             this.cityInfo=value;
             if(OnCityInfoChanged != null)
                OnCityInfoChanged(value);
       }   
  }
}
```

And

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
    Customer customer=this.currentCustomerSession;
customer.OnCityInfoChanged += new Action<CityInfo>( (cityInfo) => {//Do Something with New CityInfo});
    if(TryUpdateModel<Customer>(customer)){
       UpdateModel<Customer>(customer)
    }
    if(customer.IsCustomerNameModified ){
        //I am able to detect whether the customerName value has been changed in the frontend.
    }
    if(customer.IsCityModified){
        //I am not able to detect whether the city value has been changed in the frontend.
    }
}
```